# pass measure to SQL Query in Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have the below SQL Query

```
select * from table1 
(where filed like 
     (select field from users 
          where (UserName=@CurrentLoginUser)
     ) 
 + '%')
```

I added the above query in Power BI, I would like to set this SQL parameter "@CurrentLoginUser" with the **current user** who browses the report.

- Is it possible to do that in Power BI?
- Is it possible to pass a measure to SQL Query?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: 1. Yes it's possible. It's called Row level security.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls. 2. It's only possible to use a measure in Power BI when first running the query although you might be able to use something called the parameter table dax pattern to do it: https://www.daxpatterns.com/parameter-table/. I suggest you google a little harder in future

Comment: Thank you so much, I just have one issue in using RLS, How can I use Like as SQL in Dax Table Filter in Manage Roles in Power BI

Comment: You have no `LIKE` in your sample query. But anyway. Did you try using it in Power BI? What issue did you have?

Comment: yes it's not supported I need an alternative to do it, by the way add your comment as answer to upvote it :)

Comment: If `LIKE` is not supported then you'll need a intermediate security table that maps every single login to whatever grouping you need

Comment: Could you please tell me How can I do that?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly. Security is complicated, and you haven't explained it properly. Your SQL query makes no sense. If you can't explain your security I'm not going to guess. Also I've only done security in SSAS Tabular, not in Power BI and I'm not going to teach myself right now. All the information is online. You need to read it and try a few things. I see no error messages explained in your posts and no sensible code which tells me _you haven't actually tried anything_. Sorry I can't help any further.

Comment: I reformatted and reread your SQL and it makes a _bit_ of sense. What happened when you replaced `@CurrentLoginUser` with `userprincipalname()`? Also there is an issue with your query if `users.UserName` is not unique.

Comment: This https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-string-comparison/ has the DAX replacement for `LIKE` so you should start there.

Comment: Many thanks , please add your answer to accept it

Comment: TBH I don't have an answer here ,just some grumpy general guidance. This would be of most value if you were to document your own findings in an answer

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I really appreciate your support, so please add the links and guidelines as an answer to accept it :)